# RxJava wait for the response to be retrieved before moving on

Tags: android, rx-java

```
        getRemarks(licensePlate)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(response -> {
                Store.remarks(response);
            }, throwable -> {
                Timber.e("Error", throwable);
            });

    public static Observable<List<Remark>> getRemarks(String number) {
        return getApiService().getRemarks(number);
    }
```

So, for now this is my code but I need to wait until this method get the response before moving on with the code. As I saw I need .toBlocking (but it blocked my code indefinitely) and I read somewhere that I need .forEach method but don't know how to use it.

Comment: did you get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `subscribe` use:

```
.toBlocking()
.forEach(new Action1<List<Remark>>() {
    @Override
    public void call(List<Remark> remarks) {
        Store.remarks(remarks);
    }
});
```

Anyway, unless you are using this for test, I would avoid to use `toBlocking` and I would look for a different strategy. `toBlocking`, indeed, returns a `BlockingObservable` that as the [documentation says](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observables/BlockingObservable.html):

> It can be useful for testing and demo purposes, but is
>   generally inappropriate for production applications.

Consider to exploit the real power of RxJava, through the stream compositions. You can take a look [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Combining-Observables) for understanding which are the available options for combining `Observable`s

Answer (score 0):

if `getRemarks()` is using retrofit then you can do something like following which will execute synchronously (you will need to be running in non-UI thread if you do this to avoid `NetworkOnMainThreadException`)

```
getApiService().getRemarks(number).execute()
```